# Flex item content overflows container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have setup the following layout. The `content__item` elements (which are commented below) are overflowing vertically outside `main` container.

```css
.root {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}

.nav {
  width: 16rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

.menu {
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: blue;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.content__item {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div className="root">
  <nav className="nav"></nav>
  <main className="main">
    <div className="menu"></div>
    <div className="content">
      <!-- Overflowing -->
      <div className="content__item"></div>
      <div className="content__item"></div>
      <div className="content__item"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

I am pretty sure its a flexbox bug. I tried using `min-height: 0` on the container but it still doesn't work. I setup an environment [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/flexbox-bug-nn6kv) for reference.

Comment: It would be helpful to also see the CSS here. I doubt very much the bug is in Flexbox which is used successfully in millions of other web pages.

Comment: @RichardHunter Flexbox has always have had bugs. Now I am not sure if thats the case now but I would appreciate if proven otherwise. I used Tailwindcss which is pretty simple to understand just by looking at the class names but if you have a hard time, I can translate the specific classes. I also setup a codesandbox so you can see the issue.

Comment: This question is tagged HTML and CSS so please create a [MRE] with the relevant HTML and CSS that shows the issue so we can help. If you need help with the Tailwind part then tag it as such so that people who are following that particular tag can help. If you could create a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) it would make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: The problem is that main is a block and you set the first div height to 4 rem and the second to 100% so it overflows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the content_items are overflowing is because height: 100% causes problems with `flex`. However if you remove that, the elements don't appear to fill the available height. This is because their parent (the `content` div) is not the child of a flex element, so it is in fact *this* element and not the `content__item` that isn't taking up the available height.

We can fix this by adding `display:flex` to the `main` div (the parent of `content`)... however now we have another problem! This makes the other child of `content` (the `nav` element) appears to the side. To fix this, we can use `flex-direction: column;`

**The main changes you need to make this work as as follows:**

```
.main {
  flex-grow: 1;            /* you already have this to allow the children grow */
  display: flex;           /* Add this so the content element can use the full height */
  flex-direction: column;  /* Add this to make the children stack one below another */
}
```

```
.content {
  display: flex;          /* you already had this */
  flex:1;                 /* Add this to make it take up the available height */
}
```

```
.content__item {
  flex: 1;                /* You don't actually need this now */
}
```

**Working Example:**

Also FYI, you need to set the `body` margin to 0 - otherwise the `100vh` extends larger than the screen as it is getting added to the default margin.

```css
body {  margin:0; }
.root {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}

.nav {
  width: 16rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: green;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.menu {
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: blue;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2rem;
  flex:1;
}

.content__item {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <nav class="nav"></nav>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <!-- Overflowing -->
      <div class="content__item">some text here</div>
      <div class="content__item">some text here</div>
      <div class="content__item">some text here</div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}

.nav {
  width: 16rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: green;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu {
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: blue;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2rem;
  
    flex: 1;
}

.content__item {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <nav class="nav"></nav>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <!-- Overflowing -->
      <div class="content__item">a</div>
      <div class="content__item">b</div>
      <div class="content__item">c</div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I am aware that adding `flex` to `main` would fix the issue. But why is that?